# Update values passed to Backbone view

Tags: backbone.js

In addone i m creating new object of view like that

```
this.section = "aaa";
var sectionview = new AA(model:this.model,section:this.section);
```

section is global variable of another view that i m passing to AA view.But after passing section its value get change at end of add one like this

```
this.section = "aaa";
var sectionview = new AA(model:this.model,section:this.section);
.
.
.
.
.
.
this.section = "sss";
```

then how i can update value of section that i passed at time of creation of view AA???
Expected answer is

```
this.options.section = "sss" not "aaa"
```

in AA view

Comment: i am bit confused. where you receive wrong value? inside `AA` or inside `addone` view?

Comment: i am not getting wrong values anywhere..i just want updated value of section in AA view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach to this sort of thing is to extend [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to build a global pub/sub event dispatcher:

```
window.pub_sub = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);
```

Then your view could listen for events from `pub_sub`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(pub_sub, 'change:section', this.section_changed);
    //...
},
section_changed: function(section) {
    this.section = section;
    // And whatever else needs to happen...
}
```

Then trigger the event when you change the section:

```
pub_sub.trigger('change:section', new_section_value);
```

You'd want to funnel all changes to the global section through a single function call somewhere to ensure that the events are triggered but you should be doing that sort of thing anyway.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rPtfS/

If you need these settings to persist then change `pub_sub` to a global settings model and use the usual model persistence mechanisms.